# UWP Azure Storage Uploading Failed

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, azure-blob-storage

I am facing a problem while uploading my webcam video file to azure storage account:

```
async void upload()
{
    try
    {
        await utility.container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        var blob = utility.container.GetBlockBlobReference(recordStorageFile.Name);
        await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();

        var fileStream = await recordStorageFile.OpenSequentialReadAsync();

        await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream.AsStreamForRead());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        status.Text = "Failed to Upload";
        var msg = new MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Uploading Error").ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

In the above code everything works fine, storage connection works perfectly, recordStorageFile have a file in it however I am getting **Access Denied** Exception at :

```
var fileStream = await recordStorageFile.OpenSequentialReadAsync();
```

Please help me out in fixing the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the file is accessible for reading?

Comment: Ummm yes I guess.

Comment: Can we see how you get `recordStorageFile`, because it really looks like you don't have read access for the file. Do you know that your app is inside isolated container with a lot of restrictions on accessing the filesystem?

Comment: It seems that App could not access the webcam video file, please tell us where does the webcam video file store and how do you get StorageFile **recordStorageFile**. It is better if you could share us your code of retrieving the file.